# What is the simplest rocket design that can reach orbit

Tags: rockets, orbit, history, design

I am curious on what the simplest possible rocket design that have been proposed which could reach orbit.
My first thoughts would be earlier rockets like the Atlas LV-3B, but then I consider the stranger designs by OTRAG, through those don't appear to be confirm to be able to work.

Comment: How many orbits and what type of orbits would you consider to satisfy the terms of your question?

Comment: I don't really have any requirements. Perhaps LEO for more than one orbit?

Comment: @Uwe "Nobody did it with only one stage." does not mean that "A rocket with at least two stages is needed." Certainly it's achievable. and as pointed out in answers to [Has humanity launched a SSTO ... ever?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12552/12102) *commercially viable* launches come close with Atlas-B being the closest (it "cheats" by dropping spent boosters, but does not need an actual 2nd stage to reach orbit). So the OP's question is valid and answerable because it doesn't ask about what's been done, only what would be simplest if SSTO was a goal.

Comment: different but relevant: [Which launch vehicles are considered SSTO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3477/12102) and [one answer to *Falcon 9R as SSTO*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21764/12102) says a Falcon 9 core could do it (Musk quote + someone's simulation). If you had money, that would be "simplest" in that you could do it with out doing the engineering yourself, but in terms of simplest design, we'll have to wait for answers. Probably a whole big string of SRB segments stacked together and a robusified nozzle that lasts long enough.

Comment: The simplest rocket is a solid fuel rocket. (The simplest liquid fuel rocket is a pressure-feed rocket.) if you want simple and reliable, go for a Minuteman. It has 3 solid fuel stages. The first has 200,000lb thrust and the second stage 45,000. Without dong the math, my guess is you could loft a small satellite to LEO with just the 2 lower stages. Not bad for no moving parts.

Comment: I am not really concern about the number of stages, but rather the technical complexity of the rocket.

Comment: If you don't care about launching an actual payload you can get very simple with a solid rocket I expect.

Comment: No orbital launch vehicle is really "simple". Making a solid fuel motor capable of orbital launch that doesn't kill the creators in the process or blow up the vehicle isn't "simple". Don't try it at home. Relatively maybe, but untold hours of engineering work went into everything that ever launched a payload into orbit.

Comment: Reaching orbit with a single stage only may be possible but is very difficult. Nobody has done it yet. With a two stage rocket it has been done very often.

Comment: Perhaps the first Japanese orbital payloads? The rockets that launched them were little more than scaled up amateur rockets  (though given that fact that they were not allowed any sophisticated guidance at all after their involvement with he axis powers in WII, the fact that they made it to orbit at all is seriously impressive).
They had a completely passive guidance for the first stage at least, with a tilted launch ramp and fixed fins being the only way to control it.

Comment: The simplest would be simply a solid single stage with the guidance (if any) as the only payload. The whole rocket should be highest percentage fuel mass to total mass as possible, so as to reduce the structural weight.
Fins for passive guidance, using the gravity turn to make it into orbit.
Perhaps a second set of small insertion motors could be fired at apoapsis to raise the periapsis above the karman line........
Not sure if that helps...
I didn't want to put this as an answer as I do not have a way to prove this, but it seems logical.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on exactly what you mean by simple, the [SS-520](https://spaceflight101.com/ss-520-4-smallest-orbital-rocket-set-for-launch/) might count (see the later [SS-520-5](https://spaceflight101.com/japan-ss-520-5-launch-success/) for a successful launch).  No guidance, just point it and let it go and stage for a bit.  As far as I know it's still [the smallest orbital rocket](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18789/how-small-could-an-orbital-rocket-be/).  Not that small implies simple, but the SS-520 happens to be both.

EDIT: looks like I was incorrect; [the second stage also does a one-time re-direction using cold gas thrusters](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/220135773.pdf), which requires a full GNC suite.  This rocket isn't that simple at all.  I'm a liar!  Take those upvotes away

Comment: I always wondered how the SS-520 was guided having all its stages powered by solid rocket motors. So even the last stage doesn't need to be guided to inject into orbit? It's just spun up from the beginning and maintains its spin to keep it stable and on track?

Comment: @JamesCraft as far as I'm aware, its only control response is that it can replan the ignition time of the upper stages

Comment: @JamesCraft It has 2nd stage nitrogen cold gas thrusters. [("SS-520 Nano satellite launcher and its flight result")](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/220135773.pdf)